# PCB components identification and reference designators?

Tags: motor, integrated-circuit, controller, induction

[image: Pcb image]

[image]

This is a motor controller for evaporative air cooler. I'm new to electronics so I'm trying to understand this chip upside down. But I have a problem with these components. 
1. Q2 , I think it's transistor but I'm not sure.
2. EC3 (ss 100 16v) i think it's an oscillator but who knows. 
3. EC4 battery?
4. REC1 no idea what it could be.
5. The IC f8234. I looked for the datasheet online but couldn't find anything.
and I would like to know if it's possible to draw the schematic from the pcb for more understanding of the controller.

Comment: Q2 : transistor. (You can look up its markings) EC3 and 4 : electrolytic capacitors.  REC1 : remote control (infra-red) receiver. f8234? good luck with that. It's probably a mask programmed MCU with no available data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! what is a "masked" programmed MCU?

Comment: It's one that you don't get to read or reprogram, as it was programmed by a "mask" layer when the chip was made.

Answer (score 1):

Q2 is a SMT transistor in what's known as a SOT-23 package -- there will be a short (3 character or so) code marked on it that can be looked up in a SMT guidebook online to find the full part number.  ECx are electrolytic capacitors (why EC and not C? designer preference I suppose).  REC1 is a remote control IR receiver -- these are basically commodity parts these days.  The IC is indeed probably a microcontroller, perhaps mask programmed and house or otherwise custom marked instead of carrying full manufacturer markings.

Comment: Much Thanks ! so the REC1 could be used for remot control? Also, how can I get myself a schematic to know how exactly the circuit works?

Comment: @AmjadIzz -- you won't be able to figure out much from one as the IC does all the grunt work.